# react native push notification IOS 'addListener is not a function'

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native

I am trying to set up push notifications for my project using react-native-push-notifications `nmp module`. It seems to be great and very useful, It works almost great on android but i can't get it to work on ios. I do everything according docs of PushNotificationsIOS but when i call 
`PushNotification.configure({..})`
it gives me this error :

```
Unhandled JS Exception: this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function.(In 'this._nativeModule.addListener(eventType)', 'this._nativeModule.addListener' is undefined)
```

but if i call `PushNotification.requestPermissions()` or other functions it works and permissions are there.

I tried to erase node-modules and 'npm install' - doesn't help. Also if i call anything from PushnotificationIOS (react native module) i have the same error.
i use react-native 0.31

It seems that I am doing something obvious wrong but I can't figure out. Any ideas would be appreciated very much!

Comment: So i solved this issue with a bit of magic. It worked on react native0.27 and did not on new versions. i deleted node modules installed react-native 0.33 and react 15.3.1 with it , cleared derived data and cleaned project then i did all steps from docs again and it worked. The thing is that I did it already 5 times before and it didn't work but this one was some kind of magical, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you add event listeners with the method `addEventListener`, not `addListener`, though the problem you are facing may be in the source code for `react-native-push-notifications`. I just looked at their source code, and it looks like they are calling `addEventListener`. I would try running `npm update --save react-native-push-notifications@latest` to grab the most recent build of the package.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the error. `addListener` is actually called successfully. It's *inside* the react `addListener` code that it attempts to call `this._nativeModule.addListener` and that's what fails.